# Django Website Not Displaying Expected Content

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm new to Django and am building a site for reminders. However, I see a blank page on launch. My base.html has a form for reminders and a display section, index.html has a similar form, and styles.css is for styling. Static paths seem fine, server runs with no errors, and migrations are updated, but still no content. Here's my code:

`base.html

Reminder Form

## Set Reminder

{% csrf_token %}{{ form.as_p }}Set Reminder

### Reminders

  {% for reminder in reminders %}
- {{ reminder.time }} - {{ reminder.title }}: {{ reminder.message }}
  {% endfor %}

`

`index.html <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}{{ form.as_p }}<button type="submit">Set Reminder</button></form>`

`styles.css *{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}body{font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;background-color:#3618bb;color:#4c34a3;}.container{max-width:1200px;margin:0 auto;padding:20px;}h1,h2,h3{margin-bottom:20px;}input[type="text"],input[type="submit"]{padding:10px;margin-bottom:10px;}input[type="submit"]{cursor:pointer;background-color:#333;color:#8b1818;border:none;}`

Any ideas what's wrong?